# Reading bytes from file to compute its SHA256 hash

Tags: java, performance, file, hashcode

I need to get text hash (sha 256), so I need to convert file to its type representation.  Is this a fast way to get a byte representation of a file?

```
public byte[] bEad(String FILENAME) {
    RandomAccessFile f=null;
    try {
        f=new RandomAccessFile(FILENAME, "r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] b=new byte[0];
    try {
        b=new byte[(int) f.length()];
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        f.readFully(b);
        f.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;

}

MessageDigest name=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
name.update(bEad("D:\crytp.txt"))
```

Comment: Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Have you tested this code? Does it work for you? It sounds like you are unsure about what your code does.

Comment: it's working and run fast, (I share my solution).

Comment: Can you please show your real code, where you are calling the `name.update` and instantiating the `MessageDigest`?

Comment: Do you want to get feedback on your code, or what exactly is your purpose of posting this here?

Comment: I need a feedback

Answer (score 1):

If have no idea what `bEad` means, or why your function is named that way.  Also, it should probably be a `static` method, since it uses no object state.

By convention, all-caps names, like `FILENAME`, should be used only for constants.

Your error handling is bad.  Suppose the file does not exist… then what?  You'll get a `NullPointerException` after printing a stack trace.  The correct thing to do is not to catch any of the exceptions.  Just declare that the method `throws IOException`.

This code could be expressed more succinctly using [`Files.readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-): see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231444/1157100):

```
byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename));
byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(b);
```

Note, however, that that solution, as well as your, scales poorly for large files, since you read the entire file into memory.  It would be better to compute the message digest by [reading, say, 8192 bytes at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304350/1157100).